# Unity app crashes on Google Tango device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I created a new Unity Project which just has a simple Main camera and a Directional Light. I added the scene and chose Android as my build environment. When I "Build and Run" my Unity app always crashes and does not start the game. I tried building the same apk on other (non-tango) android device and it seems to load fine. I haven't even added my Tango prefabs yet (although i did try adding them but no luck). 
Am I missing something ? Has anyone else experienced this problem ?

P.S.: My other tango unity samples seem to run fine.

Comment: There is not much useful info you shared, I suggest check the permission for Tango. Android Permission for Camera. and etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try following the steps in https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/unity/unity-prefab-motion-tracking. They also have some suggested Player Settings for Default Orientation (Landscape Left) and Min API (17).

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling "Dynamic Batching" in android player settings and disable "Draw Default UX Exceptions" in Tango Ux Script, which did the trick for me